# Best way to show a rating/score which also needs to be an apparent button

Tags: buttons, mobile-application, interface, ratings

I've been stuck on a presentable design solution for some time now. I'm trying to simplify the UI so the user can see the ratings/score for all (Affordability, Scenery and Safety) for a specific location but also understand that this element is a button and will open a overlay with more information about that rating category.

The issues I'm encountering so far are:

- **Rating with no text**: Less apparent of the specific rating type
- **Rating with no button background/border**: Less apparent it's interactable

Are there any standard ways of showing this or does anyone have a design in mind that may work for this scenario? Anything suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Figma File**: https://www.figma.com/file/gBb0WUjOP900EWqVOSWBJg/App-Ratings-Decision?type=design&node-id=10-970&mode=design&t=IXMlpKKSsITlYsr5-0

*(Shows a couple of my ideas, however I'm not convinced by them)*

Comment: Please add some images of the design instead of a link to Figma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly for a rating I would recommend using an integer or a float number instead of a line mainly because it would be more convenient for the user to compare it to other locations. An example is down below.

[image]

Next, to indicate to user that it is actually a CTA and not just plain diagrams I would use a rectangle just like you did.

[image]

One more note: I'd either change the icons to be more representable to the CTA's as right now they are very subjective or even get rid of them.

[image]

Another option would be to use an accordion list, example down below.
[image]

Also I'd like to mention a few reasons why I believe the second example you've shown isn't UX friendly:

- it's recommended to use icons with text, not only icons. There are a few exceptions, for example if the meaning behind icon is universally recognized, in your case not a single icon is universal and that's why a text should be provided;
- A line doesn't look like it belongs to the rating button.

**Keep in mind that colors and font that you are currently using doesn't pass WCAG. I would recommend you choosing colors that has a better contrast.**

[image]

Comment: This is very informative, I'll take these suggestions forward, thankyou.